# Find the first n digits of the square root of a number

Tags: code-golf, math

Given two integers `m` and `n`, return the first `m` digits of `sqrt(n)`, with the decimal point. They will be given with a space in between.

You only have to produce `m` digits: so if `m=5, n=500`, then the output will be `22.360`, not `22.36067`.

**Do not use anything that will increase the precision of any operation.**

Test Cases:
`20 99` -> `9.9498743710661995473`
`15 12345678` -> `3513.64170057221`
`16 256` -> `16.00000000000000`
`2 10000` -> `10`

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Looks like your second test case gives the square root of `12345678` not `1234567` (which is 1111.11070555548 according to my J program).

Comment: When you say 'do not use anything that will increase the precision of floating points.' does that disqualify arbitrary precision languages (such as bc)

Comment: @Gareth: Yeah, it's probably 12345678, I probably copied it from WA wrong.

Comment: @Matt: No, as long as you don't use any command that explicitly sets the precision.

Comment: @beary605 If I can't change the precision of my square root operator (set at 6 figures by default in J) how am I supposed to complete the task? If you want us to calculate the square root without using a square root function shouldn't you just ask us to do that?

Comment: @Gareth: It doesn't cover all of the points. You could use Newton's Method with `x^2` as the input, but the precision would be finite if you did it the obvious way.

Comment: What should `2 10000` output? `100`?

Comment: @Inkbug: `10`. I will add that to the test examples

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 143 chars

```
m,n=map(int,raw_input().split())
d=10**m
n*=d*d
a=0
b=n
while a<b-1:c=(a+b)/2;a,b=[[c,b],[a,c]][c*c>n]
print('%d.%0*d'%(a/d,m,a%d))[:m+(a/d<d)]
```

Computes the answer by multiplying `n` by `10^2m`, doing an integer square root (using binary search), then "dividing" the result by `10^m`.

Comment: This doesn't work for large perfect squares that request small numbers of digits. ex: m=2 n=1000000 will print 100 instead of 10

Comment: @Matt: fixed...

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <strike>66</strike> <strike>272</strike> 240 chars

**New approach**

This uses the same, reasonably efficient (59 chars), method for obtaining the smallest useful convergent of `Sqrt[n]`. It takes a slightly different approach for dividing the numerator by the denominator, accurate to `m` places.

```
t = ToString; q = QuotientRemainder;
w = FixedPoint[(# + n/# )/2 &, 1, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^(-m) &)];
r = q[Numerator@w, k = Denominator@w];
h[{c_, d_, e_}] := {Append[c, q[d, e][[1]]], 10 q[d, k][[2]], k};
t@r[[1]] <> "." <> t@FromDigits@Nest[h, {{}, 10 r[[2]], k}, m][[1]]
```

**Example: Find the Square root of 5 accurate to 18 places**

```
n=5; m=18;
<run the above code>

(* out *)
"2.236067977499789696"
```

By the way, the convergent, w, for the above case is given below.

This is still long-winded but it works.

---

**Old approach**

The following 59 chars suffice to produce a fraction that will, in decimal form, solve the problem, assuming m, n are entered programmatically:

```
FixedPoint[(# + n/# )/2 &, 1, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^(-m) &)]
```

When m=18, n=5, here's the fraction:

```
(* out *)
562882766124611619513723647/251728825683549488150424261
```

The trick is to convert this fraction into a decimal.
The easy way is to use `N`;

```
N[%, m+1]
(* out *)
2.236067977499789696
```

However, `N` violates the rules by specifying the precision to work with.

---

Back to the drawing board:

```
q = FixedPoint[(# + n/# )/2 &, 1, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^(-m) &)];
f[{a_, n_, d_}] := 
   With[{q = QuotientRemainder[n, d]}, {Append[a, q[[1]]], q[[2]], d/10}]
   StringInsert[IntegerString@FromDigits@#[[1]],  ".", -1/Log[Denominator@#[[3]], 10]] 
   &[NestWhile[f, {{}, Numerator@q, Denominator@q}, Length@#[[1]] < m &]]
```

Unfortunately, it takes another 205 characters (by my reckoning) to generate a decimal expression from the fraction.  Surely there must be a more direct way to divide one integer by another to m decimal places!

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell 126

```
main=interact$(\[x,y]->(\s->if '.'`elem`s then(x+1)`take`s else x`take`s)$(show.sqrt.fromIntegral)y++cycle"0").map read.words
```

Darn `sqrt` not taking `Int`s, and `fromIntegral` being so long!

Answer (score 1):

**C# 41 chars**

```
Math.Sqrt(n).ToString().Substring(0,m+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Version-1**

C# ***364*** Characters (Short Version)

```
using System;namespace X{class T{static void Main(string[] a){int m=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());Console.WriteLine("{2}",f(n,m));}static string f(long s,int l){decimal x=s;for(int i=0;i<20;x=(((x*x)+s)/(2*x)),i++);var b=x.ToString(string.Format("F{0}",l));return(x.ToString().Contains("."))?b.Substring(0,l+1):b.Substring(0,l);}}}
```

code can be ran from OneIDE - http://ideone.com/9tZsD.

C# Normal  Version

```
using System;

namespace X
{
    class T
    {
        static void Main(string[] a)
        {
            int m = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine()), n = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("m:{0}, n:{1} -> {2}", m, n, f(n,m));
        }
        static string f(long s,int l)
        {
            decimal x = s;
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; x = (((x * x) + s) / (2 * x)), i++) ;
            var b=x.ToString(string.Format("F{0}", l));
            return(x.ToString().Contains("."))?b.Substring(0,l+1):b.Substring(0,l);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for all the test cases: test case #4 (2, 10000) should output 10, not 100.00. As well, #1 and #2's outputs are cut off at 13 digit precision.

Comment: tx @beary605 for pointing out issues around #4, updated code with new oneide link

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 142 bytes

This full `program` requires a processor supporting features of “Extended Pascal” (ISO standard 10206).
The `program` will crash if `m` is negative.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var n,m:integer;p:string(maxInt);begin read(m,n);writeStr(p,sqrt(abs(n)):1:m);write(p:m+ord(index(p,'.')in[1..m]))end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program findFirstNDigitsOfSquareRootOfANumber(input, output);
    var
        number, digit: integer;
        print: string(maxInt);
    begin
        readLn(digit, number);
        
        { `Sqrt` only works on non-negative integers and always returns
          the principal root as a `real` value. The `writeStr` routine is
          defined by Extended Pascal. The `:1` specifies the minimum width
          of the given argument. The write routines in combination with a
          `real` argument accept a second format specifier (here `:digit`)
          that disables scientific notation and determines the number of
          post-decimal (i.e. fractional) digits. }
        writeStr(print, sqrt(abs(number)):1:digit);
        
        { The format specifier `:digit…` in combination with a `string`
          argument specifies the _exact_ width. We will need to take
          account of the radix mark (`'.'`) _if_ it is printed, though. }
        writeLn(print:digit + ord(index(print, '.') in [1..digit]));
    end.
```

It is not possible to request `maxInt` digits since one `char` value will be occupied by the radix mark (`.`).
You will probably need to replace `maxInt` by a sufficiently small natural number, though.